# Get "null" when I'm using getResourceAsStream to read properties file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I recently just start to using Android Studio for my programming study.

I've faced a problem today which is keep getting "null" when I using getResourceAsStream to read a properties file from JUNIT TEST.

I used to locate the .properties file under "src" directory when I was using Eclipse. But in Android Studio, it won't work.

Here is the code that part of a class called BeanFactory,:

```
private static Properties properties;

static {
    properties = new Properties();
    InputStream is = BeanFactory.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("bean.properties");
    try {
        properties.load(is);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In Eclipse, I located the the prop file under src, and it works just fine.

But in Android Studio, I've tried put the "bean.properties" file in several different directory. Such as /src, or/src/main/java, nothing worked out.

Where should I put the prop file? Is there any configurations that I should do for this?

Answer (score 1):

Placing resources into assets is not acceptable in some cases. I solved this problem by packing required resourses into special jar file and placing this jar into libs directory.Thus you still can access them via standard Java technique.

Comment: Any idea what one needs to do for resources in a java library module the main Android module depends on?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues. In general resources are stored in a jar, with the compiled .class files.
`getResource` and `getResourceAsStream` are methods of a class. The resource is searched in the jar of this class (in general). So with inheritance `getClass().getResource("...")` might be dangerous.

The second, more grave pitfall is, that the path is *relative* to the package (directory) of the class, unless you use "/...".

Another way is to use ResourceBundle instead of Properties. ResourceBundle has a PropertiesResourceBundle for *.properties.

```
ResourceBundle properties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bean");
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:
1.put your own bean.properties file in app/src/main/assets
2.change you code to:

```
private static Properties prop;

static {
    prop = new Properties();
    try {
        InputStream is = IWorkApplication.getInstance().getResources().getAssets().open("bean.properties", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prop.load(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

PS.`IWorkApplication.getInstance()` is define in my own application class.
Hope to be useful

Comment: This will work, but in most cases you don't really want those files to be included in the app build, since they are dummy data for unit tests.